# Magento model->save() doesnt working

Tags: magento

Hello my model save() function doesnt work. Magento cache turned off. My code below:

```
$newInventory = Mage::getModel('reservation/newinventory');
Mage::log( get_class( $newInventory ) ); //print Apptha_Reservation_Model_Newinventory

$newInventory->setEntityId( $productId ); 
$newInventory->setRoomTypeId( $roomTypeId );
$newInventory->setRoomsCount( $roomsCount );
$newInventory->setDateFrom( $checkInStamp );
$newInventory->setDateTo( $checkOutStamp );
$newInventory->setOrderId( $orderId );

$query = $newInventory->save();

Mage::log( "save query below: " ); //I get this string
Mage::log( $query->toString() ); //return 2012-10-15T06:00:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): 17, 7, 8,
                                //1349913600, 1349913600, 300000040, 12
```

This is my code\local\Apptha\Reservation\etc\config.xml

```
 <models>
        <reservation>
            <class>Apptha_Reservation_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>reservation_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </reservation>
        <reservation_mysql4>
            <class>Apptha_Reservation_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
               <newinventory>
        <table>apptha_booking_hotel_newinventory</table>
       </newinventory>
            </entities>
        </reservation_mysql4> 
</models> 
    <resources>
        <reservation_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Apptha_Reservation</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </reservation_setup>
        <reservation_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </reservation_write>
        <reservation_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </reservation_read>
    </resources>
```

What I make wrong? Why new row doesnt appear in db?

**UPDATE 1**

In my index.php I have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//}
```

**UPDATE 2**

My code\local\Apptha\Reservation\Model\newinventory.php below

```
class Apptha_Reservation_Model_Newinventory extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('reservation/newinventory');
}
}
```

My code\local\Apptha\Reservation\Model\Mysql4\newinventory.php below

```
 class Apptha_Reservation_Model_Mysql4_Newinventory extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{

protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('reservation/newinventory', 'id');
}

}
```

So I dont get any errors from Magento. It looks like Magento find all pathes (model, resource and etc.) But anyway can't save() my data.

**UPDATE 3**
I inserted code to log queries in Mysql.php to  public function query($sql, $bind = array())

```
    $code = 'SQL: ' . $sql . "\r\n";
if ($bind) {
    $code .= 'BIND: ' . print_r($bind, true) . "\r\n";
}
Mage::Log("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] ".$code);
```

Then I get in log file:

```
2012-10-15T09:54:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): [2012-10-15 09:54:31] SQL: INSERT INTO 
`apptha_booking_hotel_newinventory` (`entity_id`, `room_type_id`, `rooms_count`, `date_from`,
`date_to`, `order_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
BIND: Array
(
[0] => 17
[1] => 7
[2] => 8
[3] => 1349913600
[4] => 1349913600
[5] => 300000040
)
```

I try manually execute this query in phpmyadmin, It`s working fine. But Magento can't make it.

**UPDATE 4**

okay. While I was debuging this issue, I have written additional testModel action in the controller where tried to test save() function. I saw, It worked there.

Then I returned to originally function and discovered when I make save() outside of if-block then save() works fine. if I make save() inside if-block,then it doesn't work.

I log some string inside if-block and make sure, execution go inside if-block. So actually question why save() doesn't work inside if-block below:

```
    if ( $state == "complete" ){
    Mage::log('here');
        $newInventory = Mage::getModel('reservation/newinventory');
        $newInventory->setEntityId(12);
        $newInventory->setRoomTypeId(7);
        $newInventory->setRoomsCount(8);
        $newInventory->setDateFrom(1349913600);
        $newInventory->setDateTo(1349913600);
        $newInventory->setOrderId(300000040);

        $query = $newInventory->save();
    die;
   }
```

but if condition will be

```
if ( $state === "processing" )
```

then It works fine. This code are in observer function when order status is changed. When admin make "invoice" for product, producr state is changed from "processing" to "complete". Thefore Magento go into the function two times. First time on  "processing" save() working fine but on "complete" It doesn't work.

Comment: You make wrong you telling of steps to debug.

Comment: Alan, when I create model I folow steps from your blog. Just now It's my own model to impore extention. I wrote code above but can't understand why It's not working.

Comment: People need more information than "it doesn't work" to help you.

Comment: understand you. I have  turned on display_errors and error_reporting. But I really don't get any errors from Magento. And It's strangle.

Comment: a bit late at the party, but if the PK of your table is not auto incremental, you have to add `$this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;` in your model resource's construct. Otherwise save() will not work silently. source: http://watson-net.com/blog/magento-database-model-primary-keys/

Comment: @OSdave that was really helpful, I could have never figure it out, this worked for me thanks for sharing!

Comment: @OSdave: Thanks a lot. I was searching this for more than two hours. Your solution works perfectly and +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So problem is in some  internal Magento processing. I have spent 1 day to understand it.

But Stop now and solved it by using another observer event  sales_order_save_commit_after where I check order state is completed and use save() function. And sure here It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some serious doubts that **$newInventory** contains your model. You are declaring entity **hotel_newinventory** in config.xml, but trying to load entity **newinventory**. You can check it this way:

```
Mage::log(get_class($newInventory));
```

If I'm right and result is not your model class, try changing the following line

```
return Mage::getModel('reservation/newinventory');
```

to

```
return Mage::getModel('reservation/hotel_newinventory');
```

Comment: ok, I have changed my config.xml from hotel_newinventory to just newinventory. In addition, I adde to my answer model and resource files. I made Mage::log(get_class($newInventory)). It return properly class name. But still can't save.

Answer (score 0):

you can also persist models with the "sales_order_place_after" (no need to use "sales_order_save_commit_after") Event.

You just can't stop execution because the sql transaction is not finished in "sales_order_place_after" nothing will be written directly but later when the transaction is commited to the database.

hope this helps someone.